# Error when submitting registration form Joomla 3

Tags: sql, joomla3.0

When a user clicks register on my site they get an error

SQL:

```
UPDATE `jos_user_usergroup_map` 
SET user_id = 93 , group_id = 
WHERE user_id=93
```

This doesn't affect the registration, the users are been added to the database.  How can I stop this error from showing?

Answer (score 0):

`group_id =`  has no value. Check your sql paramaters. For joomla Registered group's default id is 2. So you can give the value manually.

```
UPDATE `jos_user_usergroup_map` SET user_id = 93 , group_id =2 WHERE user_id=93
```

You can find the default id's for user groups for Joomla!

```
1 Public 
2 Registered 
3 Author 
4 Editor 
5 Publisher 
6 Manager 
7 Administrator 
8 Super Users 
9 Guest
```

Another point is why do you update `user_id` while it is same? There is no need.

```
UPDATE `jos_user_usergroup_map` SET group_id = 2 WHERE user_id=93
```

Comment: I probably should have been more specific. I haven't written any SQL for this to happen I honestly wouldn't know the first thing about it.  Is there a way I can just remove this altogether?

Comment: @user1851954 of course there is a way. Check the error.log and find the line on which error occurs in which file. Then try to modify it or show us.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a value for `group_id`

```
UPDATE `jos_user_usergroup_map` 
SET user_id = 93, 
    group_id = 
WHERE user_id=93
```

Should be like this

```
UPDATE jos_user_usergroup_map
SET group_id = 123
WHERE user_id = 93
```